# React able to render arrays of elements without using .map?

Tags: reactjs

I'm going through a book to better learn React and came across a surprising example. I previously thought that in order to render an array of anything in React, we need to map each element of the array, and pass them keys (I know keys aren't absolutely mandatory but a best practice so React knows which element to re-render upon change.)

But here is a working example of an array being rendered without needing to do anything special to it:

```
const Tail = ({number, children}) => (
  <div>
    Last {number} children:
    {React.Children.toArray(children).slice(-number)}
  </div>
)
```

Is this something special about children? Why is React able to render an array like this? There aren't even keys specified!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So `React.Children` provides utilities like `toArray`, `map`, `forEach` etc for dealing with the children props data structure.

In this case the `toArray`:

> Returns the children opaque data structure as a flat array with keys assigned to each child. Useful if you want to manipulate collections of children in your render methods, especially if you want to reorder or slice this.props.children before passing it down.

Here are the docs if you want to read more: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html

Comment: I see, that explains why we don't need to pass in keys. Would it be correct to say that actually React has no issue rendering any arrays, and the reason we usually map them to render is because the items in the arrays don't usually come as React elements?